# How to find input and output arrays for Tensorflow frozen graph

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to find input arrays and output arrays for the frozen graph so that I can convert may model to Tensorflow-lite.
There is a tool available to visualise the frozen graph which is netron["https://netron.app"].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using Netron, you can choose to view model properties (Ctrl + Enter), and you can see the name of the input array:

[image: Input array for netron]

To find the output array, you could follow the nodes of the model until the last layer, and click on that to see the name of the output array.